# Can i eject react-dev-utils files?

Tags: reactjs, webpack-dev-server, hot-reload

Can someone tell me if is there any way to override webpackHotDevClient.js file (which is in the react-dev-utils package)  and the webpack.config.js (which is in the react-scripts package) ?

edit : i have tryed eject command and i have the webpack.config.js in a config folder but not the webpackHotDevClient.js file

In the webpackHotDevClient i want to change :

```js
// Connect to WebpackDevServer via a socket.
var connection = new WebSocket(
  url.format({
    protocol: 'ws',
    hostname: window.location.hostname,
    port: window.location.port,
    // Hardcoded in WebpackDevServer
    pathname: '/sockjs-node',
  })
);
```

to

```js
// Connect to WebpackDevServer via a socket.
var connection = new WebSocket(
  url.format({
    protocol: 'wss',
    hostname: window.location.hostname,
    port: window.location.port,
    // Hardcoded in WebpackDevServer
    pathname: '/sockjs-node',
  })
);
```

And in webpack.config.js change the publicPath property to publicPath: "/Apps/MyApp/app/". Because my app is in mydomain.com/Apps/MyApp/app/

So i can use hot dev server reloading through https.

**edit** : i have tryed eject command and i have the webpack.config.js in a config folder but not the webpackHotDevClient.js file. So is it possible to have an equivalent or a work around so i can edit the webpackHotDevClient.js settings as said above. Right now i'm directly editing the file in the node_modules folder.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue. react-dev-utils is part of Webpack and as far as I can tell this will not be fixed until Facebook devs update Webpack.

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8079

The above reference gives you a fix to edit the file (if your issue is local) but when Heroku references it, Heroku does not use your fixed version, so you should upload it in your deploy by not ignoring it. Add this to your .gtignore AFTER you update the node_module as referenced above.

```
node_modules/*
!node_modules/react-dev-utils
```